# How do I resolve an error that shows up in Chrome but not Firefox using cola.js with d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, cross-browser

Update: here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuh5akmL/10/) that exhibits the behavior described below. Comment/uncomment javascript lines 290/291 to switch between the network that works in Chrome and the one that doesn't.

---

I'm trying to set up a force directed graph with groups that can expand or collapse on click, similar to [GerHobbelt's example](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3071239) for d3.js. I'm using cola.js with d3 because I need geometric constraints.

I've set up a [script](https://github.com/shortda/colaCables/blob/master/colaCollapse.html) that works fine in both Chrome and Firefox (versions 44.0.2403.125 and 39.0 respectively). That script visualizes [this JSON network](https://github.com/shortda/colaCables/blob/master/cableTest.json), which has seven nodes, five links, and three groups. If I switch to [this network](https://github.com/shortda/colaCables/blob/master/cables.json) instead (comment line 309, uncomment line 310 in my script), which has a few hundred nodes and links, and 25 groups, then the Chrome javascript console gives me thousands of `assertion failed` errors as soon as it starts. The visualization is a little glitchy (nodes jump back and forth over the edges of group rectangles) but it seems to run okay despite the errors. Using  the non-minified versions of [cola](https://github.com/shortda/colaCables/blob/master/cola.js) and [d3](https://github.com/shortda/colaCables/blob/master/d3.js), all the errors have the following stack trace:

```
generateConstraints @ cola.js:1479
generateGroupConstraints @ cola.js:1428
generateYGroupConstraints @ cola.js:1524
Projection.project @ cola.js:1673
Projection.yProject @ cola.js:1653
Projection.projectFunctions @ cola.js:1666
Descent.stepAndProject @ cola.js:2472
Descent.computeNextPosition @ cola.js:2508
Descent.rungeKutta @ cola.js:2527
Layout.tick @ cola.js:3543
(anonymous function) @ cola.js:4063
d3_timer_mark @ d3.js:2122
d3_timer_step @ d3.js:2102
```

In Firefox, I get no errors at all with either network. I can use Firefox for now but I have no idea how to resolve the errors I get in Chrome. This is my first javascript project, so I assume I've done something stupid with scoping or function definitions.

Any advice on this would be helpful; thanks!

Comment: I've heard Cola.js has some bugs concerning webkit recently, so you may want to see if you can use anything to bypass using it. If not, bring it up with the developers. If the bugs have been fixed (or not), I still suggest posting a working example so I can take a look at both scripts and get back to you.

Comment: working example meaning jsfiddle? I'm really new to javascript, so I'm not sure what people expect when posting code for review.

Comment: Yes, meaning a jsFiddle.

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle to the post.

Comment: Thanks. First off, you have over 14000 errors. Taking a closer look at each individual one shows that there are no errors in your code itself. This leads me to believe my suspicion that it's a cola.js issue. Try to find a workaround either by using simple d3 or something like nvd3. If you can't find anything, I'll take some time to create something for you.

Comment: Thanks for the offer! I'm thinking about trying a d3-only solution but I'll have a look at nvd3. I've also made a post at the webcola git repository, so I'll get back to you soon one way or another.

Comment: Good to know. I'm around most of the time so just give me a buzz. If you want, you can email me alexey.ayzin@barstowschool.org or chat me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85149/discussion-between-alexey-ayzin-and-dshort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is resolved in [issue #130](https://github.com/tgdwyer/WebCola/issues/130) over at the webCola github repo (thanks to Tim Dwyer). The issue was that I thought I set the node boundaries at lines 313 and 314 in my JSFiddle, but node properties don't seem to be carried over properly in my `network()` function. I don't see why, but that's clearly what's happening.

The quick fix from Tim is to set the node boundaries in `init()` after getting the current network elements. See the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuh5akmL/13/).